# Enumerate GROUP_CONCAT results

Tags: php, mysql

I am grabbing some emails from my MySQL database with:

```
...GROUP_CONCAT(USERS.emails SEPARATOR '\n') as group_mail...
```

and put them into A PHP variable string:

```
...
$result=$db->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$data=$row["group_mail"];
```

By transferring $data content inside a textarea I am getting the following design:

```
 abc@gmail.com
 bcd@gmail.com
 cde@gmail.com
```

However, I'd like the following:

```
   1.  abc@gmail.com
   2.  bcd@gmail.com
   3.  cde@gmail.com
```

Consider the number of emails as known. Is it possible to change $data as to get the second appearance and how?

Thank you

Comment: You could `explode(PHP_EOL, $data);` add numbers then `implode(PHP_EOL, $data);` again.

Comment: why bother group_concatting, if you need to separate them again anyways?

Comment: This can be solved with a sinmple loop.  Have you made any effort at all to implement this?

Comment: If I knew how to manipulate PHP strings I 'd not be addressed to stackoverflow community!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we have to change SQL as follows:

```
 ...GROUP_CONCAT(USERS.emails) as group_mail...
```

Then, we have to add the folowing PHP code:

```
             $data=$row["group_mail"];
             $interdata = strtok($data, ",");
             $i=1;   
             while ($interdata !== false)
             {
               $finaldata.=$i.". ".$interdata."\n"; 
               $interdata = strtok(",");
               $i++;
             }
```

The results are the desired ones:

```
   1.  abc@gmail.com
   2.  bcd@gmail.com
   3.  cde@gmail.com
```